# Oracle Java Ubuntu Installation - Javac not functioning

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have been trying to install Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu 11.04. I was following the [instructions given here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Once I followed all the steps ( to the letter ), I tried running

```
java -version
```

which gave the expected output. But running

```
javac -version
```

did not give the expected output. Instead I get the following error:

```
Error : Could not find libjava.so
Error : Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment
```

The environment variable PATH contains both /usr/local/java/jre/bin and /usr/local/java/jdk/bin, LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to /usr/local/lib which contains libjava.so which is currently owned by the user who I am running javac as. In addition, JAVA_HOME points to the jdk folder. Inspite of all this, javac is unable to find the libjava.so file. There are multiple solutions online but none seem to work for me. Even a direct run

```
/usr/locale/java/jdk/bin/javac -version
```

results in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Which browser might be the question.   Such as Chrome is a 32 bit browser.  The new Java is a 64 bit app, and when updated, it will not work on a 32 bit browser.